# Set background row when click row in listview error

Tags: android, listview, background, android-adapter

At the moment,this is my code.
I want to create a listview ,when click row in listview,background of row change to RED.when row's color is RED,click row's color change to WHITE. 
But run app,click a row,then scroll listview,don't only color of row clicked change to RED,some below row also change to RED.

Adapter

```
public class ItemBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private String[] mArrayItems;
private Context context;

public ItemBaseAdapter(Context context, String[] arrays) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mArrayItems = arrays;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mArrayItems.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textViewItem = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewItemList);
        holder.layoutItem = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.layoutItemList);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.textViewItem.setText(mArrayItems[position]);

    holder.layoutItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (holder.isCheckLayout == false) {
                holder.isCheckLayout = true;
                holder.layoutItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                holder.isCheckLayout = false;
                holder.layoutItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewItem;
    LinearLayout layoutItem;
    boolean isCheckLayout = false;
}
```

}

And this is Activity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private ListView mListView;

String[] arrayList = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e",
        "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c",
        "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b",
        "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c",
        "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b",
        "c", "d", "e" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewItem);
    mListView.setAdapter(new ItemBaseAdapter(this, arrayList));
}
```

}

And this is xml of item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutItemList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewItemList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/action_settings"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know ,what cause is it? How must I do?

Answer (score 1):

`getView` always called **multiple** times (**example** : when your listview is being scrolled), so you must do the `if-else` operation **not** only when the button is clicked. Try to change the code to this :

```
holder.textViewItem.setText(mArrayItems[position]); 

// also add the if-else outside the onclick 
if (isChecked[position] == false) { 
holder.layoutItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); 
} else { 
holder.layoutItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
} 

holder.layoutItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

@Override 
public void onClick(View arg0) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
if (isChecked[position] == false) { 
isChecked[position] = true; 
} else { 
isChecked[position] = false; 
} 
notifyDataSetChanged(); // call the getView again 
} 
}); 

return convertView; 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I am a newbie android. Please tell about me detail . Thank

Comment: Take it easy :). Change the code in your ItemBaseAdapter with my code first and lets see what will happen. You may want to do a little research about how getView working.

Comment: Sorry. I copied your code to my project. But when click a row,background of rows is being set not true. :)..

Comment: @treehh do you mean the red become white and vice versa?

Comment: yes. i want to don't use checkbox in each row. instead of i will change background color of row. (sorry my english is not good)

Comment: @treehh my english is also not good :) Where do you set holder.isCheckLayout value? You did the selection in the onClick, but where do u set its value?

Comment: static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewItem;
    LinearLayout layoutItem;
    boolean isCheckLayout = false;
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64120/discussion-between-blaze-tama-and-tree-hh).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem.
This is my code Adapter

```
public class ItemBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private String[] mArrayItems;
private Context context;
boolean[] isChecked;

public ItemBaseAdapter(Context context, String[] arrays) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mArrayItems = arrays;
    this.isChecked = new boolean[mArrayItems.length];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mArrayItems.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textViewItem = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewItemList);
        holder.layoutItem = (LinearLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.layoutItemList);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.textViewItem.setText(mArrayItems[position]);

    // also add the if-else outside the onclick
    if (isChecked[position] == false) {
        holder.layoutItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else {
        holder.layoutItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }

    holder.layoutItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isChecked[position] == false) {
                isChecked[position] = true;
            } else {
                isChecked[position] = false;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged(); // call the getView again
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewItem;
    LinearLayout layoutItem;
}
```

}